# write sed commands to multiple lines

Tags: sed

I am taking efforts to learn sed and encounter such a situation

```
$ echo "abcd" | sed -n "/b/p"
abcd
```

it works properly,

```
$ echo "abcd" | sed -n "
→ /b/p"
abcd
```

good again, but

```
$ echo "Abcd" | sed -n "/b
/p"
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated address regex
```

What's the problem with the error report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/b/p` is a complete sed command.  Each sed command needs to be on a single line.  When you say `/b` on one line, sed treats it as a syntax error.  You can try by

```
echo "abcd" | sed -n "/b"
```

and see the result.  You can also try

```
echo "abcd" | sed -n "/b/p
> p"
```

and observe that after the command is completed, the next command takes effect.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` patterns are fundamentally line-based, so it expects the second slash to be on the same line as the first one. From `info sed`:

> Commands within a SCRIPT or SCRIPT-FILE can be separated by semicolons (';') or newlines (ASCII 10).

Answer (score 1):

Most commands in Linux are fundamentally line-based, so it expects the second slash to be on the same line as the first one. In your case to work for 3rd one you can use the below

```
$ echo "Abcd" | sed -n "/b\
 /p"
 Abcd
```

Comment: With "line based", one usually means that the _data_ is read in a line based manner. Program code is usually multi-line.